# yii2 Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 134217728) (tried to allocate 6291464 bytes)

Tags: php, apache, yii2

I am trying to read csv of having more than 30k records from Console and browser.
When I use it from console shell script in yii2 its working fine. 
But when I use a browser then it displays an error.

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 134217728) (tried to allocate
>   6291464 bytes) in \backend\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-debug\LogTarget.php on
>   line 123

Even if I have allocated more memory as required like 512m.
But still same issue.

Comment: Try turning off yii2-debug logger

Comment: "_Even i have allocated more memory_" Make sure you edited the correct `php.ini` file (the one for your server, not the CLI one) and restart your server afterwards.

Comment: @Justinas : It's not working

Comment: @kerbholz: Yes, i have made changes on right php.ini and restart the server but still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can chunk this file, for example

```
$csv = new SplFileObject('data.csv');
$csv->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);

foreach(new LimitIterator($csv, 0, 500) as $line){
   //work with $line
}
```